# Re-render React useState without updating the state

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I need to re-render this state manually.

```
const [person] = React.useState(new Person());
```

I have methods inside the Person class to update it (e.g. `person.setName('Tom')`).
When I update person using a method from itself, it does not trigger a re-render on the person state.

```
const carouselData = React.useMemo(() => {
  // Doesn't re-render when the fields on the person class update
}, [person]);
```

Is there a way to force this state to re-render without using a setState function?
Ideally, is there a way to call that re-render from inside the Person class itself?

Or is this totally misusing the useState functionality? Would there be a better React hook to connect this to?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an antipattern to use mutable classes as the state object, since hooks are designed around immutable references. If the instance remains the same between renders, then passing it into a dependency list will not allow React to detect a change within the object.

Answer (score 1):

Person could be a prop or in context instead. First create your instance outside of your component.

`const person = new Person([]);`

Then pass `person` as a prop.

```js
function App({person}) {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = useState(person.personName);

  function handleNameChange(txt) {
    person.addTodo(txt);
    setPersonName(person.personName);
  }

  function handleSubmit(txt) {
    handleNameChange(txt);
  }
  
  return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are indeed miss using it, react relies heavy on functional programming. you should be doing something like:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState(new Person());
...
setPerson(setPersonName(person, 'Tom'));
```

that's just a silly example but you get the gist. react will only re-render if state is changed, it won't monitor if the state object is mutating or anything like angularjs used to do